# retrieving data from mongodb in jade template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm new to node and mongodb and am trying to render a database query in a template, but I get the error that the property is undefined:

```
Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
```

Here's my index.js file:

```
var dburl = 'localhost/olpdb';


var collections = ['users'];


var db = require('mongojs').connect(dburl, collections);

var currentUsers = db.users.find();

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', currentUsers);
};
```

In the index.jade template, I've got:

```
#{currentUsers.firstname}
```

I've queried the database separately and know that there is a record:

```
> db.users.find()
{ "firstname" : "andy", "lastname" : "johnson", "email" : "andy@johnson.com", "_id" : ObjectId("51adf8a8c58996cf0c000001") }
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to pass the object to the template so that I can extract the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `currentUsers` is probably an API object (a Query or similar). In order to use the query's result, you need to use a callback:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  db.users.find(function(err, currentUsers) {
    res.render('index', {
      currentUsers: currentUsers
    });
  });
};
```

Now you can use the `currentUsers` **array** from your Jade template:

```
#{currentUsers[0].firstName}
```

Comment: This gives me the error: Cannot read property 'firstname' of null